# User input to update excel

Tags: excel, matlab

I want this code to check if the user input is pasta or pizza if it is then the dialogue will appear so that the user changes the password and then the new password is updated in the excel file:

This is the code I tried but it didn’t update the excel sheet;

```matlab
x = get(handles.edit1,'string');

% Get the correct password

global i

if i == 1

    x1 = "pasta";

else

    x1 = "pizza";
   

end

% Check if the user input is correct

if strcmp(x, x1)

    % If the input is correct, ask the user to enter a new password
   
    new_password = inputdlg('Enter a new password:', 'Change Password', 1, {'0000'});
   
    % Save the new password in the Excel file
   
    if i == 1
   
        writematrix(new_password, 'Data.xlsx', 'Sheet', 'Sheet1', 'Range', 'B1');
   
    elseif i == 2
   
        writematrix(new_password, 'Data.xlsx', 'Sheet', 'Sheet1', 'Range', 'B2');
   
    elseif i == 3
   
        writematrix(new_password, 'Data.xlsx', 'Sheet', 'Sheet1', 'Range', 'B3');
   
    end
```

Comment: What version of MATLAB are you using?